# WordPress : get iso language

Tags: wordpress

How can I get iso code language in WordPress?
This function :

```
get_bloginfo('language');
```

return me the languge like this : en-EN

I create a function like this :

```
<?php
function pr_language() {
    $lang = get_bloginfo('language');
    $pos = stripos($lang, '-');
    $lang = substr(get_bloginfo('language'),0,-($pos+1));    // retourne "f"
    return $lang;
}
?>
```

Is it correct? I want to display en not en-EN

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I hope I understood your question. It seems like all you want to display is en-US.

According to [WordPress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/bloginfo),

**Usage:**
`<?php bloginfo( $show ); ?>`

**Parameters:**
`language`

So,

**EXACT CODE:**
`<?php bloginfo('language'); ?>`

**Will output:**

> en-US

To show only en, just display first two characters.

```
function show_short_language() {

    <?php echo substr( get_bloginfo ( 'language' ), 0, 2 );?>

}
```

**Just a note for anyone in the future:**

`<?php echo substr( get_bloginfo ( 'language' ), 0, 2 );?>`

Produced:

> en

**and**

`<?php echo substr( bloginfo ( 'language' ), 0, 2 );?>`

Produced:

> en-US

Comment: i want to display en not en-EN or en-US

Comment: So if you only want it to display the first two letters of language code you can just count from left to right for two spaces.

Comment: It dose not work when the user site is in a different language and the admin dashboard is in English. In Ajax's request, it always returns en. You should use get_locale() function instead.

Comment: this wouldn't work for three-letter language codes, such as `tzm-Latn-DZ` `sma-NO` `sma-SE` `smj-NO` `smj-SE` `smn-FI` `sms-FI` `sah-RU` `qut-GT` `quz-BO` `quz-EC` `quz-PE` `nso-ZA` `prs-AF` and others.

Answer (score 8):

There are language codes with 3 letters rather than 2, so you shouldn't use `substr`. I did:

```
$lang = explode('-', get_bloginfo('language'));
$lang = $lang[0];
```

Comment: Unfortunately, i got `it_IT`, instead of `it-IT`, so the explode isn't a reliable meaning, unless you verify the length of the string you've got and possibily perform a second explode, to be sure of the results :-)